# Does dying of a non-critical service, kill System server

Tags: android, android-framework

We know that a lot of system services run as threads inside System server process.

In that case, can the dying of a service like 'isub' kill the system server. Or to say in slightly different terms, does a service related to telephony send a SIGKILL signal to system server if it is dying?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with killing a service but when any thread in java process dies and nobody handles the exception then the whole java process dies with it.

Comment: @zapl: Thanks. Yes, i meant dying of a service. I observe a service dying, and following it, all services start dying. Looks like, killing of other services is due to system server receiving a signal 9. Not sure, who sent it the signal from the logs.